# Why does rebasing master give many conflicts but merging give none?

Tags: git, github

Correct me if I am wrong but I think the only benefit of using `git rebase master` when on a feature branch is to keep your history clean.

However, when I try to do a `rebase` it consistently runs into many conflicts and keeps getting stuck so I have to

1. fix merge
2. git add .
3. git rebase --continue
4. repeat step 1.

However, when I do a git merge master there is only a conflict on one file. Why is this happening? How can I prevent it? Can I just skip all conflicts and fix that one file manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git rebase` attempts to merge each changeset individually. This is why you have to continue. `git merge` only needs to merge the current branch with the merged branch. There are many more opportunities for merge conflicts with rebase since it has to do many merges.

The main benefit of `git rebase master` is to pull in features and fixes you want in master to your dev branch, or to make sure that the final merge back to master won't produce any conflicts since all those changes are already in the dev branch.

Comment: is it best practice to continually rebase your features/fixes?

Comment: Depends on the kind of branch, I think. Don't worry about best practices, do what makes sense.